# RAILS Save csv file on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

In my rails app, I can download data as csv file.

This is my current code

```
response_to do |format|
   format.csv {send_data #MY_DATA#}
end
```

Instead of this code, I want to save the csv file on server.

How can I generate csv file and save the file on the server

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to generate a CSV on server.

```
CSV.open("#{Rails.root}/public/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

Comment: your code worked, but I need to save the file on s3 after generate     AwsWrapper.write_object('aa_sites_files', s3key, "MYFILE", nil), Do I need to save the file first on server? or there is the option to generate the file and save it on S3